# NullPointerException at ExpandableListAdapter.getChild()

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, expandablelistview, android-adapter

Been stucked at here more than a week but still unable to solve! I have an `expandable listView` where the data were retrieved from `SQLite` and set to `expListAdapter`. Once the arrow clicked, it will display two child items.

**AddMonthlyExpenses**

```
public class AddMonthlyExpenses extends AppCompatActivity {

    ArrayList<ListObj> groupList= new ArrayList<ListObj>();;
    List<String> childList;
    Map<ListObj, List<String>> laptopCollection;
    ExpandableListView listview;
    ExpandableListAdapter expListAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.add_monthly_expenses);
        laptopCollection = new LinkedHashMap<ListObj, List<String>>();
        listview = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.exlistView);
        expListAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(getApplication(), groupList, laptopCollection);
        listview.setAdapter(expListAdapter);
        retrieveList(name);
    }

 public void retrieveList(String name) {
        database = mdb.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + MyDatabaseHelper.TABLE__TASK + " WHERE Name = ? ", new String[]{name}, null);
        if (cursor != null && cursor.getCount() > 0) {
            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                groupList = new ArrayList<ListObj>();
                int iD = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("ID"));
                String month = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Month"));
                double budget = cursor.getDouble(cursor.getColumnIndex("Budget"));
                groupList.add(new ListObj(iD,month,budget));
                if (expListAdapter != null) {
                    expListAdapter.add(iD, month, budget);
                    createCollection();  // for child items
                    listview.setAdapter(expListAdapter);
                }
            }
        }
    }

 private void createCollection() {
        String[] options = {"Edit","Delete"};
        for (ListObj laptop : groupList) {
            loadChild(options);
            laptopCollection.put(laptop, childList);
        }
    }

    private void loadChild(String[] laptopModels) {
        childList = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (String model : laptopModels)
            childList.add(model);
    }
}
```

**ExpandableListAdapter**

```
  public class ExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

    private Context context;
    Map<ListObj, List<String>> laptopCollections;
    private ArrayList<ListObj> laptops;
    double used = 0;
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;

    public ExpandableListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<ListObj> laptops, Map<ListObj, List<String>> laptopCollections) {
        this.context = context;
        this.laptopCollections = laptopCollections;
        this.laptops = laptops;
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {  // error line
        if (laptopCollections.get(laptops.get(groupPosition)).get(childPosition) != null && !laptopCollections.get(laptops.get(groupPosition)).get(childPosition).isEmpty()) {
            return laptopCollections.get(laptops.get(groupPosition)).get(childPosition);
        }
        return 1;
    }

    public void add(int id, String month, double budget) {
        String[] splited = month.split("\\s+");
        ListObj obj = new ListObj(id, month, budget);
        obj.setYear(splited[1]);
        obj.setMonth(splited[0]);
        obj.setBudget(budget);
        obj.setID(id);
        laptops.add(obj);
        this.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return childPosition;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return laptops.size();
    }

    public ListObj getItem(int position) {
        return laptops.get(position);
    }

    public View getChildView(final int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
                             boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        final String laptop = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);   // here the error line 
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.child_item, null);
        }
        TextView edit = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textEdit);
        edit.setText(laptop);
        return convertView;
    }

    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        if (laptopCollections.get(laptops.get(groupPosition)) != null && !  laptopCollections.get(laptops.get(groupPosition)).isEmpty()) {
            return  laptopCollections.get(laptops.get(groupPosition)).size();
        }
        return 1;
    }

    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        return laptops.get(groupPosition);
    }

    public int getGroupCount() {
        return this.laptops.size();
    }

    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        return groupPosition;
    }

    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
                             View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ExpensesAdapter.ViewHolder holder = null;

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.expenses_adapter, null);
            holder = new ExpensesAdapter.ViewHolder();
            holder.month = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textMonth);
            holder.budget = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textAmount);
            holder.year = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textYear);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ExpensesAdapter.ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        holder.month.setText(laptops.get(groupPosition).getMonth());
        holder.budget.setText(String.format("%.2f", laptops.get(groupPosition).getBudget()));
        holder.year.setText(laptops.get(groupPosition).getYear());
        return convertView;
    }

    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return true;
    }

    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

**Error**

> 10-26 00:03:57.114 23612-23612/com.example.tony.monthlyexpenses
>   E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                     java.lang.NullPointerException
>                                                                                         at
>   com.example.tony.monthlyexpenses.adapter.ExpandableListAdapter.getChild(ExpandableListAdapter.java:42)
>                                                                                         at
>   com.example.tony.monthlyexpenses.adapter.ExpandableListAdapter.getChildView(ExpandableListAdapter.java:87)
>                                                                                         at
>   android.widget.ExpandableListConnector.getView(ExpandableListConnector.java:451)
>                                                                                         at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2232)
>                                                                                         at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1849)
>                                                                                         at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:678)
>                                                                                         at android.widget.ListView.fillSpecific(ListView.java:1339)

My apps screen shot

[image]

I tried debug but nothing is null !

[image]

You can clone my project from link below

https://github.com/wseng92/MonthlyExpenses

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: put a break point in this line `if (laptopCollections.get(laptops.get(groupPosition)).get(childPosition) != null && !laptopCollections.get(laptops.get(groupPosition)).get(childPosition).isEmpty())`. And check if anything in this is null

Comment: Can you post a simple project at github with that behavior?

Comment: You have to understand what a NullPointerException is, this exception is thrown when a variable is null and a method is called on it. From that your error comes from one of the following being null: laptopCollections, laptops,get(laptops.get(groupPosition)), etc. You could change your check to something like this: `if(laptopCollections != null && laptops != null && laptopCollections.get(laptops.get(groupPosition)) != null && laptopCollections.get(laptops.get(groupPosition)).get(child‌​Position) != null  && ...)`. An other idear is to use Stream Api and use the filter method to optimize.

Comment: @azizbekian You can clone my project from https://github.com/wseng92/MonthlyExpenses

Comment: @PhanVanLinh You can clone my project from github.com/wseng92/MonthlyExpenses

Comment: @MissingSemiColon You can clone my project from github.com/wseng92/MonthlyExpenses

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add createCollection(); to button1 setonclick listner

```
createCollection();
```

[image: Edit & Delete Working after above line]

groupList = new ArrayList(); is written inside for loop might be problem? It creates a new arraylist for each loop and as a result your arraysize is 1 always ( last iteration count )

```
while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                groupList = new ArrayList<ListObj>();
                int iD = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("ID"));
                String month = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Month"));
                double budget = cursor.getDouble(cursor.getColumnIndex("Budget"));
                groupList.add(new ListObj(iD,month,budget));
                createCollection();  // for child items
                if (expListAdapter != null) {
                    expListAdapter.add(iD, month, budget);
                    listview.setAdapter(expListAdapter);
                }
            }
```

change to

```
groupList = new ArrayList<ListObj>();
while (cursor.moveToNext()) {

                int iD = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("ID"));
                String month = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Month"));
                double budget = cursor.getDouble(cursor.getColumnIndex("Budget"));
                groupList.add(new ListObj(iD,month,budget));
                createCollection();  // for child items
                if (expListAdapter != null) {
                    expListAdapter.add(iD, month, budget);
                    listview.setAdapter(expListAdapter);
                }
            }
```

Comment: Tried but no luck

Comment: inside for loop do we need to setAdapter again? I think instead of multiple setAdapter calls.. just call notifyDataSetChanged after loop is complete?

Comment: You mean remove setAdapter ?

Comment: yes 2nd setAdapter is not required.. notifydatasetchanged after populating listview

Comment: I change to  `listview.deferNotifyDataSetChanged();` but still getting same error

Comment: please check my post again. Thanks

Comment: can we call createCollection(); after laptops object is populated? i.e. after add method

Comment: @JohnJoe - updated answer.. was able to get edit and delete working by adding createCollection() on line 151 in MainActivity.java

Answer (score 1):

I ran in to a similar problem year or two ago. Can not remember anymore which version it was.

Starting from call

```
public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
   if (laptopCollections.get(laptops.get(groupPosition)).get(childPosition) ...
```

What is the value of laptops? It is initialized with constructor

```
public ExpandableListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<ListObj> laptops ...
```

on second parameter, it is created on `AddMonthlyExpenses.onCreate()`

```
expListAdapter =
   new ExpandableListAdapter(getApplication(), groupList, laptopCollection);
```

and initially initialized in declaration

```
 ArrayList<ListObj> groupList= new ArrayList<ListObj>();;
```

For some reason unknown to me - Android peculiarity - in my case this `groupList` (or similar member field i had) was `NULL` even it was initialized on declaration.

But moving the initialization inside `onCreate()` fixed this problem.

Try that. Or at lease debug the row where `laptops` is referenced.

Answer (score 0):

i think in your code dont work this

`laptopCollections.get(laptops.get(groupPosition)).size();`

because try find other object instance.

you have so many list in your fragment and adapter you really dont need this. Try keep OOP and refactor this and create better model for this.

or easier way dont use for map key object but id then.

change from
`Map<ListObj, List<String>> laptopCollections`
to 
`Map<String,List<String>> laptopCollections` where first K is id.
Maybe it will be helpfull.

Comment: But I need to use Obj (ListObj) instead of String as the data were retrieved from SQLite

Comment: you really dont need use from ListObj only id like key .... map<K,T> and then use only id to find in map becouse when you use ListObj you save to map key for example ListObj@1253 and then use for finding ListObj@2569 its two different instance. Try debug your code and this code laptopCollections.get(laptops.get(groupPosition)) return null